# How can I redirect the output of one command in a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch, windows-batch

**Edit:** This question has been answered, please scroll down ⬇️

This question is related to Server Fault because I am automating minifying some web files before deploying them to my server.

So I have a batchfile which calls [minify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minify) like this:
`minify "index.html" > "index.html.minified"`

Minify basically takes in an html/css/js file from the command line parameter and "minifies" it so it'll be faster to load, then prints the minified output to stdout. I am attempting to save that output to a file, `index.html.minified`.

But commands after the one above do not execute in the batch file. What I mean is that the execution of the entire batch just stops after I call this command. The file `index.html.minified` is created correctly, but the commands after it (like `echo Done minifying HTML`) do not execute and the command window freezes to the point where I have to force it to quit.

**How can I get the batchfile to continue executing after attempting to save the output of a program to a file?**

[Link to the whole batchfile that I created, the part where I call minify is somewhere near the end](https://pastebin.com/1nbMq9PW)

Comment: Please add contents of the `minify` batch file to the question.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Done.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, so my answer to this question has been found.

Instead of trying to run the command in the current batchfile directly (`minify index.html > index.html.minified`), I could rather do it like this `cmd /c minify "Y:/wamp/www/index.html" > "Y:/wamp/www/index.html.minified"` to run it in a new instance of Command Prompt.

This solution allows the rest of the batchfile to continue execution after the seperate instance is done.